# How to make AWS Elasticache Redis split read requests across all read replicas?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a Redis Elasticache non-clustered instance with one primary node and two read replicas. Using the Stack Exchange Redis client I provide the reader endpoint and make a get request. Based on the [documentation](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/new/2019/amazon-elasticache-launches-reader-endpoint-for-redis/) I would expect:

> A reader endpoint will split incoming connections to the endpoint
>   between all read replicas in a Redis cluster.

However, 100% of the requests go to one of the read replicas. First question, why? Second question, how do I get Redis to distribute the load across all of the read replicas without having to manage the read instances at an application level?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use the "Reader Endpoint" connection string. (the connection string with "-ro")
This will split the connection between your replicas in case you have more than one connection to the Redis Cache server.  Also to achieve this you need to have significant CPU usage to the first redis-replica server.